# Liferay able to access download url even after setting permissions to owner only

Tags: liferay

I have set my the document and media portlet to be owner only permissions. However, I am able to use another user's download URL to download his files.

eg. copying

```
{mysite.com}/documents/323892/445802/{user1's file title}/2e8db841-9c7e-47ad-99c0-6496afd0ffad?version=1.1
```

and using the above URL as another user. Is there a setting to block this behavior?

Comment: When you specify you have set the permissions to owner only, what exactly does that entail. I have set the file permission to OWNER and placed the URL in Web Content Display. I get an appropriate Forbidden when attempting to access the file via the link on a different user than the owner.

Comment: I am actually getting the request and modifying the GET/POST values. Anyways I have fixed the problem by observing the relation of a document and their owners through the database

Answer (score 0):

In Documents and Media, the `"VIEW"` permission allows other users to download the file as they can VIEW them.

Please allow only "OWNER" to view the file and not to the "GUEST" or "USER".

Comment: The permissions are already set to owner. And actually, by looking at the codes, I think they only check permissions until they generate the document url. So if you know this url, you are able to access even the restricted files